# Как определить прокси / не прокси

Tags: прокси

Как узнать, юзер зашел под прокси или нет? Точно знаю, что есть способ)
Можно и php и .htaccess - без разницы.

Comment: @sh4dow мой 92.46.34.194:3128 не спалило ни там ни там)
а с Вашим палит. В общем, понял, дело это ненадежное.. спасибо!

Comment: @Ozim посмотрите обновление плз, нашел как обезвредить)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Точного способа нет. Есть Элитные (High-Anonymous ka HIA) прокси, которые нигде не оставляют пыли за собой.

Но вообще можете сравнивать переменные

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
```

И если там разные адреса - это почти наверняка был прокси (хреновый, но таки прокси))

После socks-проксей вообще грустно определять, там все заголовки ручками пишутся.

Вариант для извращенцев - отправить на `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']` запрос по протоколам CONNECT, SOCKS4, SOCKS5, так вы точно спалите все прокси без авторизации) Только предупрежу, что эти три запроса могут идти ок.10 сек в зависимости от таймаутов/отклика/нагрузки на сервер, потому для каждого юзера это делать нелогично совсем.

Еще почитайте [вот эту штуку](http://www.freeproxy.ru/ru/free_proxy/faq/anti_proxy.htm) , есть несколько нетривиальных способов. Однако упор сделан на яву и куки, первое часто отключено, второе часто чистят. А вот проверка IP в списках - неплохой способ.

**Добавлено**

```
$ip1 = @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip2 = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
$ip3 = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
if ( (!!$ip2 && ($ip1 != $ip2)) || (!!$ip3 && ($ip1 != $ip3)) )
  die('No proxy, please.');
```

**Добавлено с покаянием**

Прошу прощения, но заинтересовало и понял, что задачу я сильно усложнил =(

На самом деле факт того, что переменная `$_SERVER['HTTP_VIA']` не пуста, равен факту использования прокси. А код выше скорее предназначен для определения истинного IP. Элитные от анонимок отличает то, что их таким образом не пропалить. Но элита на то и элита, что их очень мало и найти трудно.

Итого, ваш код:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_VIA']))
  die('No proxy, please.');
```

Comment: пустота, ничего не выводят )

    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']

Comment: Они появляются при соответствующих заголовках, которые как раз прокси и добавляют.

Comment: дык как мне с их помощью определить - прокси или нет?

что то вроде:
> if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']!='' && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']!='') {die('No proxy, please.')}
?

Comment: Обновил.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. Скажите, плиз, оператор !! что значит?:)

Comment: http://subcoder.ru/proxy.php не работает..

Comment: !! - двойная инверсия, приводит к булеву виду.

Проверьте сперва <a href="http://2ip.ru/">вот здесь</a>, тут определялка сравнительно неплохая. **92.48.126.219:85** этот адрес спалила и их, и ваша.

Comment: запрос по протоколам CONNECT, SOCKS4, SOCKS5, так вы точно спалите все прокси без авторизации)  можете разжевать то есть прокси с паролем и логином не спалит? и что подразумевается под словом елитные?вип?приватные если вкурсе?